# Extract multiple floating numbers from a line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I want to extract timeTaken values from following line:

```
<some other log data> Exception, Curl1-Time: 0.258315s. Curl2-Time: 3.9092588424683s Exiting.
```

I am using following command with `grep` and `awk`:

```
grep -Po "Exception, Curl1-Time: \K(\d+.\d*)s. Curl2-Time: (\d+.\d+)" app.log | awk '{print $1 + $3}'
```

This outputs: `4.167565`

1. Can this be done in more smarter way, maybe using *sed* or any other
   bash tool.
2. Is it ok to ignore trailing "s." in time-taken
   values as the result of addition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You already use PCRE. Why not use Perl itself?

```
perl -lne 'print $1 + $2
           if /Exception, Curl1-Time: ([\d.]+)s\. Curl2-Time: ([\d.]+)/
          ' < input
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU's `grep`, then you can execute:

```
var="<some other log data> Exception, Curl1-Time: 0.258315s. Curl2-Time: 3.9092588424683s Exiting."
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+s?' <<< "$var"
```

Or you can use `awk` and stay [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
var="<some other log data> Exception, Curl1-Time: 0.258315s. Curl2-Time: 3.9092588424683s Exiting."
awk '{ while (match($0, /[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+s?/)) { print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH) } }' <<< "$var"
```

As you can see, both commands use the regex `[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+s?` to match a pattern of *one or more digits, a dot, one or more digits and an **optional** 's'*.

GNU's `grep` uses the -o option to extract the matching regex pattern.

The `awk` version uses its `match` and `substr` functions, to match and extract relevant data.
After a regex match, `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set and we can use them to calculate a *start* and *end* positions for `substr`.

`RLENGTH` is the length of the substring matched by the `match` function.

`RSTART` is the start-index in characters of the substring matched by the `match` function.

[see section Built-in Functions for String Manipulation](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_13.html#SEC126)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*Curl1-Time: \([0-9]\.[0-9]*\)s.*\([0-9]\.[0-9]*\)s.*$/\1 \2/p' filename | awk '{print ($1+$2);}'
```

- Regex pattern matching ".*Curl1-Time: ([0-9].[0-9]*)s.*([0-9].[0-9]*)s.*$"  --->  Pattern within the braces is the number matching regex.
- Entire line is replaced with two matching patterns. i.e the output of sed will be two numbers with spaces in between them. e.g. 1234 34567
- awk parses the sed output with default space delimiter and sums up them and prints the result.

Comment: A brief description of what this line is doing is extremely helpful for people trying to understand what exact problem you're trying to solve.